# Jenkins pipelines - git checkout to folder in workspace without wipe

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I would like to check out my deployment scripts which reside in separate repo to the deployment folder in my workspace. This folder already has some files in it, and the problem is that during the checkout of the scripts the folder gets cleared. I need a way to keep these files.

The code used for checkout:
...

`steps{
checkout(
    [$class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
    extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
    relativeTargetDir: 'deployment']], 
    submoduleCfg: [], 
    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'secret', url: 'https://bitbucket.org/secret/deploy_scripts.git']]]) 
}`

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

What about changing folder for checkout step?

like this [tested]:

```
node(){
    stage("checkout"){
        // `dir` step will create folder in workspace, if it is not exist
        dir('speacial_folder_for_git'){
            //git checkout here
            checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'alexkh_git_credentials', url: 'http://localhost:7990/scm/tes/mytestrepo.git']]]
        }
        // change current directory back, to workspace:
        dir('')
        {
            //do your job out of git folder
        }
    }
}
```

Files from `git checkout` will be placed in `\speacial_folder_for_git\` into your workspace, while other files outside this folder (but inside workspace) remains untouched

Answer (score 3):

It could make sense to stash a content of the directory before fetching:

```
steps{
    sh "mkdir -p deployment;touch deployment/test"
    stash name: "deployment", includes: "deployment/**"

    checkout(
            [$class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
            doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
            extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
            relativeTargetDir: 'deployment']], 
            submoduleCfg: [], 
            userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'secret', url: 'https://bitbucket.org/secret/deploy_scripts.git']]]) 

    unstash deployment
    sh "ls deployment"
    # it prints fetched repo AND existing before files 
}
```